# Websphere, perfservlet and nagios

Tags: java, websphere, nagios

Does someone know if there is a nagios plugin able to extract the metrics from perfservlet ? In fact cwas-nagios is a broken script, as said by the developer himself.

Perfservlet is a servlet installed on webpshere 8.5.7 and the output is in xml format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE PerformanceMonitor SYSTEM "/wasPerfTool/dtd/performancemonitor.dtd">
<PerformanceMonitor responseStatus="success" version="">
<Node name="myNode">
<Server name="myServer">
<Stat name="Exécution JVM">
<BoundedRangeStatistic ID="1" highWaterMark="524288" integral="0.0" lastSampleTime="1473146179159" lowWaterMark="524288" lowerBound="524288" mean="0.0" name="HeapSize" startTime="1472049293297" unit="KILOOCTET" upperBound="524288" value="524288"/>
<CountStatistic ID="2" count="201183" lastSampleTime="1473146179159" name="FreeMemory" startTime="1472049329696" unit="KILOOCTET"/>
<CountStatistic ID="3" count="323104" lastSampleTime="1473146179159" name="UsedMemory" startTime="1472049293298" unit="KILOOCTET"/>
<CountStatistic ID="4" count="1096885" lastSampleTime="1473146179159" name="UpTime" startTime="1472049293298" unit="SECONDE"/>
<CountStatistic ID="5" count="0" lastSampleTime="1473146179161" name="ProcessCpuUsage" startTime="1472049293298" unit="N/A"/>
</Stat>
</Server>
</Node>
</PerformanceMonitor>
```

Fatiha

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [Perfservmon](https://github.com/dvarounis/perfservmon).

It uses perfservlet and is based in Python.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test and I'll be return to you if I need more help.